# How to find certain folder names and rename them based on a list

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The list of folders I need to rename looks like this:

```
14029384
10934829
12039829
23409813
```

I need to rename them to corresponding named folders like below:

```
14029384 = PICTURE1
10934829 = PICTURE2
```

How do I make a script to achieve this?

There are about 100 folders to rename.

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow. Here is a quick guide to asking good questions which will get you the answers you want. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @PeterHalligan For information, if you just insert `[ask]` the link with description is inserted automatically. See [format comment](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: Kelly it depends where the table/list comes from, you usually iterate the folders with a `for` command and use find/findstr to lookup the new name. Pease take the [tour] and understand that [SO] isn't a script writing service. I'm pretty sure there are a lot of examles doing exactly what you want here on this site.

Comment: Thank you for editing my post to be more legible, and okay I'll take a look.

Comment: @KellyDavis, to do this with a Windows `.bat` file you will need to export the file from excel as a comma delimited file first.  Then it is literally one line of code to do what you want to do.

Comment: Export your two excel columns as a csv file, a batch could read that easily (a powershell script with the Import-Excel module could even read the file directly and process the folders)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you export the Excel spreadsheet to be a csv file you can use one line of code to parse the csv file and rename the directory.

Input

```
14029384,PICTURE1
10934829,PICTURE2
```

Code

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-2 delims=," %%G IN (folderlist.csv) do rename "%%G" "%%H"
```

Comment: I managed to get what I wanted through using the ren command, but your script is much more cleaner than what I did, thank you!